# Error in Installing MediaWiki for Ubuntu, Posgres 8.3

Tags: ubuntu, installation, postgresql, mediawiki

**How can you solve the error message at the last line?**

```
....
# Installing MediaWiki with php file extensions
# Environment checked. You can install MediaWiki.
#

Generating configuration file...
# Database type: PostgreSQL
# Loading class: DatabasePostgres
# Attempting to connect to database "wikidb" as "wikiuser"... error: No database connection
# Checking the version of Postgres...
Warning: pg_version(): supplied argument is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource in /var/www/wiki/includes/db/DatabasePostgres.php on line 1078
FAILED. Required version is 8.1. You have 7.3 or earlier
```

I am using Postgres 8.3 which makes the error message strange.
The file "LocalSettings.php" was not created to the directory *config* so I cannot continue the installation without solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message only says that the script tried to call pg_version() with a wrong type. So there was no Information returned about your PG Version an I assume the script only gives a Default error message, with a "custom" version number.

The Script gets an error and infact it requires Version > 8.1 it assumes that maybe the connection Problem is related to a Version prior to 8.1, so it calls pg_version().
But you never had a Database connection. And so you get this warning.

Has nothing todo with the Version you are using.